# Flexbox: display elements with number of columns and rows given

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an empty `div`.

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

With the following `CSS`:

```
#container{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In which I want to insert more `divs` via `JavaScript` but let the user choose how many rows and columns the container will have.

At the moment this is the code I have:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var rows = prompt("How much lines do you want?");
var columns = prompt("And how much columns do you want?");

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.classList.add("square");
      div.innerHTML="<p>" + i + "</p>";
      container.appendChild(div);
   }
}
```

where `square` class has the following:

```
.square{
    flex: 1;
    height: 50px;
}
```

but all the divs inside the container are displayed in one row.

What I want to do is to set the `divs` inside the container with the same dimensions that the user inputs, but I cannot get it.

Is it possible to set these `divs` inside the container as rows/columns given by the user?

**Note:** As you can see, I am **only** using `JavaScript` and I would like to keep it, so please avoid answers with plugins/libraries/etc.

Comment: Any time a user adds a column, the container direction must also change to `flex-flow: column wrap`. But a container can only have one `flex-direction`. So I'm not sure how you want this to play out.

Comment: @Michael_B But if I change it from `row wrap` to `column wrap`. Will not be all the divs in the same column?

Comment: Yes. So how do plan to enable users to choose their number of rows and columns in one container?

Comment: @Michael_B This is really the clue of my question. Because I have no idea. I though about something like a line break in a specific div inside the container but I could not find anything similar to that.

Comment: As a basic concept, flexbox is not designed to be a grid system. It's a layout system that manages space and alignment. Alternatively, once it gains browser support, you could consider [CSS Grids](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

Comment: Create classes for container like r4c4. (rows=4 cols=4) and then set for r4c4 children width: 25% height 25%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `N` columns, one solution is to set the `flex-basis` property to a percentage of `100/N`.

You can set it in javascript without libraries (as required) with:

```
div.style['flex-basis'] = 100/columns + '%';
```

Keeping the same settings as yours, you just have to add the previous line in the script like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var rows = prompt("How much lines do you want?");
var columns = prompt("And how much columns do you want?");

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.classList.add("square");
      div.innerHTML="<p>" + i + "</p>";
      div.style['flex-basis'] = 100/columns + '%';
      container.appendChild(div);
   }
}
```

You can test it with the codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGYKdY

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!